# Can't connect to router admin panel

Tags: networking

I'm connected to a  Zyxel VMG3326-D20A router through ethernet.
I'm trying to reach the admin panel from my browser. As i've understood the correct URL is my default gateway.

Output of "route -n"

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         84.250.112.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 p4p1
84.250.112.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 p4p1
```

I tried going to  84.250.112.0, and also 192.168.0.X without luck.
What's the deal?

EDIT: Output of ifconfig

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:6439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2127308 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:2127308 (2.1 MB)

p4p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:16:7e:e8:a1:52  
      inet addr:84.250.122.107  Bcast:84.250.127.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4216:7eff:fee8:a152/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:40417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:27406 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:38371825 (38.3 MB)  TX bytes:3351237 (3.3 MB)
```

Comment: Can we have the output of `ifconfig`?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Added!

Comment: Based on your output, router ip is `84.250.112.1`

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Are we talking about a corporate network here? Because otherwise, how did you end up with a public /20 subnet?

Comment: Can you ping 84.250.112.1? I think you need to describe better what your setup looks like. Are we talking about a home internet connection? If yes, the IP addresses are _really_ suspicious.

Comment: Im also wondering about the unusual addresses. It's a corporate network. The connection isn't going through a phone cable. I am forwarding the connection through an internet cable coming from my wall to my router.

Comment: --- 84.250.112.1 ping statistics ---
    1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.562/0.562/0.562/0.000 ms

Comment: Ok, the router is reachable. Then it's just like terdon says, the web-based admin GUI is disabled. SSH might work, but since we're talking corporate her, forgive me for asking, but should you even have administrative access?

Comment: I misunderstood what you asked, The network is bought from a corporation for home use. I called them a while back and they told me I should buy an ethernet modem. The current one seems to "work" though. Can i forward ports with SSH? It's all i need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have understood correctly, it is indeed the IP of your default gateway. As you can see in the output of `route`, that is `84.250.112.1`, so why are you connecting to `84.250.112.0`?

Everything should work as expected if you connect to `84.250.112.1` instead.

Comment: I've tried 84.250.112.1 also without luck. Firefox instantly says "Unable to Connect"

Comment: @Tsaldu What's the specific error? Is it `Connection Refused`? It seems like the router may have custom firmware and no web config.

Comment: @Tsaldun Also, the default IP is 192.168.10.1, not 0.1.

Comment: @Zacharee1 That surely depends very much on the model and brand of the device.

Comment: @nephente (whoops, wrong @). Yes, but I looked the exact model up and this is what I found.

Comment: Anyway, I doubt it's going to be on the default settings, and why are you trying to access it?